# AMP Script Difficulty

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

What would be the correct script for the following?

`%%FieldName%%`, fallback = no information available

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would approach it:

```
%%[

var @fieldName 
set @fieldName = AttributeValue("fieldName")

if not empty(@fieldName) then
]%%

%%=v(@fieldName)=%%

%%[ else ]%%

no information available

%%[ endif ]%%
```

or in a single block:

```
%%[

var @fieldName 
set @fieldName = AttributeValue("fieldName")

if not empty(@fieldName) then

  output(concat(@fieldName))

else 

  output("no information available")

endif 
]%%
```

or shorter:

```
%%=iif(empty(AttributeValue("fieldName"), "no information available", AttributeValue("fieldName")))=%%
```

Using raw personalization strings is risky, IMO.  If `fieldname` didn't exist in your send context for some reason, the email would blow up.  Using [**AttributeValue()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/?section=attributevalue) will return an empty string in that case.

Comment: AttributeValue() is the unsung hero of AMPScript. I use it for any and all personalization strings and it has saved my butt countless times.

Answer (score 0):

```
%%[ var @this set @this = FieldName]%% 
%%[IF @this == "" or @this is NULL THEN]%% 
some text here to signify that it's blank 
%%[ELSE]%% %%FieldName%%, 
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Taken from: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213691&type=1

Comment: Thanks Harley. Then if it was %%FieldName%% or %%FieldName%%, fallback = no information available would you know what it would be?